# If one dies in Kanchi will he get liberation too?

Tags: moksha, pilgrimage, tirtha

Is it a Mokshapuri just like Kashi is?

What scriptures talk about Kanchi as a Mokshapuri?

And if it’s a Mokshapuri why isn’t it as popular as a pilgrimage site as Kashi?

Comment: "why isn’t it as popular as pilgrimage site as kashi" -- this looks opinion based..u asked a Q in title then answered that in description and asked a new Q..can u pls specify what's ur main Q?

Comment: my main question is,if I die in kanchi will I get moksha just as if I die in kashi?my secondary question is what scripture talks about it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether Kanchi is a Mokshapuri or not. But in **[Skanda Purana,](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370642.html#note-t-138993)** it is written that doing penance in Kanchi destroys all sins.

> 59-63. There is a city named Kāñcī.[1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370642.html#note-t-138993) It is endowed with all riches and is well-known. **It is a direct representation of heaven full of Devas on the surface of the earth.** It is said that any penance performed there has infinite benefits. Devas and all the sages desire to stay there forever. There (is a river) well-known as Kaṃpā. **It is destructive of all great sins.** Crores of sins of the men staying there tremble (with fear). There is one mango tree there. It shines with perpetual sprouts. It has. perfectly cool shade along with flowers, fruits and sprouts. Japa, Homa and charitable gifts performed there yield infinite benefits.

Another [chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423744.html) mentions it as one of the seven holiest cities.

> 100. After propitiating thus Mahākāla, the lord of spirits, the Brāhmaṇa went to the city of Kāntī (Kañcī, Tamil Nadu) that is more brilliant than the three worlds. 101. It is definite that Lakṣmīkānta (Lord Viṣṇu) himself directly makes all the creatures staying here Śrīkāntas (possessors of wealth, identical with Viṣṇu) here and hereafter. 102. By visiting Kāntī (Kāñcī) which is refulgent and which is resorted to by those who are brilliant, that Brāhmaṇa also became resplendent. There is no fading of splendour of anyone there.

Anyone who [worships](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371633.html) Lord Shiva and Vishnu in Kanchi gets salvation.

> 42. In Viṣṇukāñcī Hari is directly present. In Śivakāñcī Śiva himself is present. **Since there is no difference between these two, salvation is within the reach of everyone through devotion (to either).** If they differentiate between Śiva and Viṣṇu, men will meet with evil results.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes. Kāñcī is considered as a Mokṣapurī.**

There are seven cities that are considered bestower of Mokṣa as per the Nārada Mahā-Purāṇa.

These seven sacred cities are: Ayodhyā, Mathurā, Māyā (Haridvāra), Kāśī, Kāñcī, Āvantikā and Dvārikā

> #### [Chapter 27](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12945/page/n367/mode/1up?view=theater), Pūrvārdha,
>
> Nārada Mahā-Purāṇa.
>
> अयोध्या मथुरा माया काशीं **कांची** ह्यवंतिका ।
>  पुरी द्वारावती ज्ञेया
> सप्तैता **मोक्षदायिकाः** ॥ २७-३५ ॥
>
> > 35. The following seven cities must be known as the **bestowers of the Mokṣa**
> >     viz. Ayodhyā, Mathurā, Māyā (Haridvāra), Kāśī, **Kāñcī**, Āvantikā and Dvārāvatī
> >     (Dvārikā).
>
> English Translation by Motilal Banarsidass Publisher.

There is more than sufficient literature about the fact that anyone dying in the Kāśī gets free from the cycle of birth and rebirth.

However, I didn't come across any explicit mention about the same in the scriptures, that death in Kāñcī will yield Mokṣa.
Perhaps the Nārada Mahā-Purāṇa classification of Kāñcī as a Mokṣapurī imply that only, but it's not explicitly stated.

In any case, Kāñcī is definitely a Mokṣapurī. In the popular belief though, I have definitely heard that dying in any one of these seven sacred cities bestows Mokṣa.